# Как сосчитать время в столбце таблицы?

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте.

Подскажите, пожалуйста: есть таблица Mysql, там есть столбец, в котором находятся данные по длительности телефонных звонков по разным каналам. Задача, сосчитать сколько времени в сутки загружен каждый канал. Желательно сделать это через php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй такой запрос `SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(sum(TIME_TO_SEC(time)))`

Comment: А как воспроизвести этот запрос в php? Если так: SELECT part SEC_TO_TIME(sum(TIME_TO_SEC(timer))) - ошибка.

Comment: SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(timer))) AS part FROM ... только интервал не должен превышать 24 час., что подходит по условию Вашей задачи.